Why do sandwich attacks still exist on jito?
Why does jito have abandoned the mempool subscription method, but there is still a sandwich attack in jito's tips account? How did they do it? Or is it that jito’s internal developers are exploiting vulnerabilities?
https://solscan.io/account/FpaE1bn48rwmka1RW2R1he1VUYncU9qLBM1xT6f8WQcT
so many sandwich attck


Its still happening just there is no mempool anymore. You can hear about the details here.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wXBWb2LrD08
